# Determine what has access denied on WPP

Tags: 2010, access-denied, web-part-page

We have a large SP 2010 farm running with heavy customization, and there's a lot of problems with users having correct permissions on a site, but no permissions on a couple of lists with broken-inheritance that are on the root page. I know it's not very good business practice to do this, but we don't own or control the content.

EX:

```
SiteA -> User has read
SiteA/default.aspx has ListA list view webpart
SiteA/Lists/ListA -> User has no permissions
User gets Access Denied
```

With the heavy customization, we have a custom access request system. The only problem with it is that there's the above case where the information we gather from the `Source` in the query string isn't the actual resource causing the access denied.

The end goal here is to have a custom access denied page that'll redirect to my custom access request system, and report the correct resource. The problem is that it's currently reporting the wrong information as to what the user is getting access denied on. Right now, a user will submit an access request for `SiteA` when, in fact, they already have access to `SiteA` but needs access to `ListA`.

Is there any way to determine exactly *what* has access denied on a particular web part page programatically?

Comment: One thing to try (don't have an SP2010 right now under my hands to test properly): navigate to `SiteA/default.aspx?contents=1`. This may get you a list of Web parts on the page; the ones that fail would show-up as "Error Web part".

Comment: Any way I could do that programmatically? I'll edit the question to include the goal of this.